# Finite differences of a complex function

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers, derivative

I have a function (a complex array of values `uul(:)`) for which I would like to compute its derivative. I simply use central finite differences

```
uulder=(uul(3:end)-uul(1:end-2))./deltaeta(2:end-1)'/2;
uulderabs=(abs(uul(3:end))-abs(uul(1:end-2)))./deltaeta(2:end-1)'/2;
```

I plot this:

```
>> plot(eta,abs(uul))
>> hold on
>> plot(eta(1:end-2),abs(uulder))
>> hold on
>> plot(eta(1:end-2),uulderabs)
```

[image: Function and derivatives]

It seems the red curve is incorrect while the yellow one is correct. However, I would need the vector whose absolute value gives the yellow curve (and not taking absolute values beforehand like with uulderabs). I need this because with the yellow curve I am losing the real and imaginary parts and I would like to be able to use them. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: The yellow curve is the derivative of the magnitude of `uul`, not of `uul` itself. `uulder` is the correct complex-valued derivative of `uul`. Plot the real part of your function and of the derivative, and the imaginary parts too. You’ll see they are correct.

Comment: But what about the absolute value (magnitude)? how can I recover the yellow curve from uulder?

Comment: The yellow curve is not related to `uulder`. Please revise your math.

Comment: Let me explain with a real-valued function so you can plot and understand better: f=x. df/dx=1. Now look at the absolute value of f, and it’s derivative: abs(f) and d/dx(abs(f)). For any negative x, the derivative is -1, not 1! Obviously f and abs(f) are two different functions, with different derivatives.